# Why log4net is not logging messages

Tags: log4net

I have a console application for which I am trying to setup logging with log4net.
I have done all the basic steps for setting it up -

1. Added Configuration in App

```xml
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
  <add key="LogFileRootFolderPath" value="C:\TestApplicationLogs\"/>
</appSettings>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="TestApplication.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
    <maximumFileSize value="15000KB" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="{%level}%date{MM/dd HH:mm:ss} - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="All" />
    <!-- You can use levels, in increasing order of verbosity: Off, Fatal, Error, Warn, Info, Debug, All -->
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

P.S. I have created a new folder 'TestApplicationLogs' in C:\

1. Added `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` in AssemblyInfo.cs
2. In Program.cs

```cs
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
        (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     log.Info("App Started");
}
```

Can anyone please guide what is missing?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was looking for the log file at wrong place :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you define that C:\TestApplicationLogs as the directory where it should log to.
In the log4net config you have just specified the file name, so it will log to the directory where you execute your exe.